# Missing bin/debug/netcoreapp3.1 & bin/restore/netcoreapp3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC project. However, this project is missing the content on those folder -> `bin/debug/netcoreapp3.1` & `bin/restore/netcoreapp3.1`. May I know how to retrieve those back?

[image]

Comment: Rebuild the project? That's what generates these (`bin` contains your _compiled_ code).

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar I have tried rebuild but not working on Debug folder><

Comment: Well, your project's build configuration is probably set to "Release" (see left of the Play button). It will only build the configuration you have selected, be it Debug or Release.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### Specific

In order to get them back you need to rebuild the project in `Debug` and `Relase` configurations.

##### General

These folders should not be part of the your repository. Your .gitignore should exclude them.

You can use this .gitignore from Microsoft: https://github.com/Microsoft/dotnet/blob/master/.gitignore, for example.

After adding these folders to `.gitignore` you'll still have to remove them from the repo because they are already in the repository.

Comment: have tried rebuild but not working on Debug folder

Comment: Have you changed frameworks? e.g. 3.1 to .net6?

Comment: didn't change because this project need to be run on 3.1